# chrome extension executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an question about "**executeScript**". I know chrome extension can use chrome.tabs.executeScript to inject javascript code to page,but can I inject some code into the iframe page(not the same origin with parent page)? I'm create an extension that I want to access the iframe from  parent page(like listen click event in iframe..),but **XMLHttpRequest** seem not to access iframe page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `allFrames: true` to have the script execute in the tab iframes as well.

[method-executeScript](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)

Comment: Can I inject code only in iframe, because use `allFrames: true` seem to inject parent page and iframe. Thanks for help.

Comment: Nope. You will have to write the code to tell if it is injected in an iframe or not.

Comment: I had know how to do it. Thanks abraham!!

Comment: great fix. Works like a charm